# Derivation of Cartesian equations of conic sections

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

[image][image]

I tried to derive a formula of a horizontal ellipse and that of a hyperbola and I cannot succed. Many alleged proofs online seem to me no proof at all other than somehow helping memorize the equations.

$x^2+y^2=1$ is an equation of a unit circle because $\{\text{points}:x^2+y^2=1\}=\{\text{points}:\text{distance from origin is } 1\}$, which is equivalent to say $x^2+y^2=1\iff \text{distance from origin is }1$.
So to my understanding, a formula is an equation of an ellipse (or a hyperbola) iff it is equivalent to the definition of the conic section. But many proofs I have seen so far only proves the implication. And they are no different to say $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ is a formula for an ellipse (or a hyperbola).

To prove the equation of a hyperbola, I started with $\left|[(x+c)^2+y^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}-[(x-c)^2+y^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}\right|=d$ where $d>0$. But no matter what I do, I end up with an expression where I cannot cancel a $\frac{1}{2}$ power because I cannot square both sides. For example, I get $2x^2+2y^2+2c^2-d^2=2\left[(x^2+y^2+c^2+2xc)(x^2+y^2-c^2-2xc)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I am not able to cancel the $\frac{1}{2}$ on the right because $\left[\left(2x^2+2y^2+2c^2-d^2\right)^2\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$ might equal $d^2 -2x^2-2y^2-2c^2$ and the converse is not true. The same thing happens with an ellipse.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried squaring your equation and canceling terms of degree $4$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I tried and it didn’t work.

Comment: $$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=\pm d$$

$$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=\pm d+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}$$

$$(x+c)^2+y^2=(\pm d+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2})^2$$

$$(x+c)^2+y^2=d^2\pm 2d\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+(x-c)^2+y^2$$

$$2xc=d^2\pm 2d\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}-2xc$$

$$(4cx-d^2)^2=4d^2((x-c)^2+y^2)$$

$$(16c^2-4d^2)x^2-4d^2y^2+d^2(d^2-4c^2)=0$$

Comment: That is $x^2/(d/2)^2-y^2/(c^2-(d/2)^2)=1$ or $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1,$ with $d=2a$ and $b^2=c^2-a^2.$

Comment: I don't think line 3 is correct. Can you explain it?

Comment: You should @ me if you want a timely response. $$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=\pm d+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}\tag{2}$$
$$(\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2})^2=(\pm d+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2})^2$$
$$(x+c)^2+y^2=(\pm d+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2})^2\tag{3}$$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland If $d$ is $-d$, your second equation in this comment does not lead to the first one.

Comment: You only need the implication

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Can you explain that your equation does not lead to points that are not part of the hyperbola?

Comment: I didn't claim that. You should edit your question to address this point.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Then can you explain why an equation that leads to points not part of a hyperbola is an equation of a hyperbola?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Is $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ also an equation of a hyperbola?

Comment: Again, that should be your question. It's a better one

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland That was what I originally asked for. Now I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland How do you know the denominator under $y^2$ is greater than 0 so it can be written as $b^2$? Can you please explain it since it is not part of the definition?

Comment: I would assume $2a\neq 0,$ $c^2-a^2>0$ and then $b^2$ is just a name for $c^2-a^2.$ If $c^2<a^2$ the equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ does not represent a hyperbola, but an ellipse. Furthermore $\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=\pm d$ doesn't have real points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already seen (in the comments) a demonstration that if
$$\left\lvert\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}\right\rvert = d$$
with $d > 0$ then
$$ \frac{x^2}{(d/2)^2} - \frac{y^2}{c^2-(d/2)^2} = 1. $$
Now we can simply write $d = 2a$ in order to match the definition that you quoted, and this implies that $d/2=a,$ which produces the conventional denominator under $x^2.$

Next, recall that for any point $P=(x,y)$ on the hyperbola and for the foci at $F_1 = (c,0)$ and $F_2=(-c,0),$ where $c > 0,$
the definition of the hyperbola says that
$\lvert PF_1 - PF_2\rvert = 2a > 0.$
But the points $P,$ $F_1,$ and $F_2$ also form a triangle (possibly degenerate), and the triangle inequality implies that
$\lvert PF_1 - PF_2\rvert \leq F_1F_2 = 2c.$

In the case where $\lvert PF_1 - PF_2\rvert = 2c$ the only possible points on the "hyperbola" are the points on the $x$-axis outside the interval between the foci. This is generally not considered a conic section, so we can exclude this case.

Therefore $2c > 2a > 0,$ and so $c > a > 0$ and $c^2 > a^2,$
so $c^2 - a^2 > 0.$ Since $c^2 - a^2$ is positive, we can take its square root; set $b = \sqrt{c^2 - a^2},$
and then we can write $b^2 = c^2 - a^2 = c^2 - (d/2)^2$
so that the denominator of $y^2$ can be written as $b^2.$

That's one of the directions of implication, namely, that if $(x,y)$ is on a hyperbola with foci at $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$ and if the absolute difference of the distances from every such point $(x,y)$ to each of the foci is $d,$ then
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag1$$
where $a = d/2$ and $b^2 = c^2 - a^2.$

---

Now let's do the other direction. We will assume $(x,y)$ satisfies Equation $(1)$. Without loss of generality we can also assume $a > 0,$ since replacing $a$ with $-a$ does not change the solution set of Equation $(1)$.  We then show that $(x,y)$ lies on a hyperbola with foci at $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$, where $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, and that the absolute difference between the distances from $(x,y)$ to each focus is $2a.$

First, note that $(x,y)$ satisfies Equation $(1)$ if and only if $(-x,y),$
$(x,-y),$ and $(-x,-y)$ all satisfy Equation $(1).$
That is, whatever figure is formed by the points that satisfy this equation,
the figure is mirror-image symmetric across the $x$ axis and across the $y$ axis.
We can therefore describe the entire figure by finding the part of it in the right half-plane, that is, for $x \geq 0,$ and reflecting it across the $y$ axis.

In the following, therefore, we will assume that $x \geq 0.$

Next, Equation $(1)$ implies that
$$y^2 = \frac{b^2}{a^2} x^2 - b^2. $$
Also, $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ implies that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$
Therefore
\begin{align}
(x\pm c)^2 + y^2 &= x^2 \pm 2cx + c^2 + \frac{b^2}{a^2} x^2 - b^2 \\
&= \left(1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}\right) x^2 \pm 2cx  + c^2 - b^2 \\
&= \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2} x^2 \pm 2cx  + a^2 \\
&= \frac{c^2}{a^2} x^2 \pm 2cx  + a^2 \\
&= \left(\frac ca x \pm a\right)^2. \\
\end{align}

Now, $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ also implies $c \geq a,$
and Equation $(1)$ implies that
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} = 1 + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \geq 1, $$
which implies that $x^2 > a^2,$ which implies $x > a$ (since we have assumed that $a > 0$ and $x \geq 0$).
Therefore  $\frac ca x \geq x \geq a$. It follows that
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac ca x - a\right)^2}
 = \left\lvert\frac ca x - a\right\rvert = \frac ca x - a,$$
and of course
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac ca x + a\right)^2}
 = \left\lvert\frac ca x + a\right\rvert = \frac ca x + a.$$

Now we put these facts together. The distance from $(x,y)$ to one focus is
$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}$ and the distance to the other focus is $\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2},$
so the absolute difference of these distances is

\begin{align}
\left\lvert\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}\right\rvert
&= \left\lvert\sqrt{\left( \frac ca x + a\right)^2} - 
       \sqrt{\left( \frac ca x - a\right)^2}\right\rvert \\
&= \left\lvert\left(\frac ca x + a\right) - \left(\frac ca x - a\right)\right\rvert\\
&= 2a,
\end{align}

showing that $(x,y)$ is on the hypberbola with foci at $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$
such that the absolute difference of distances to the foci is $2a.$

In conclusion, Equation $(1)$ is satisfied by the points on that hyperbola and *only* by the points on that hyperbola.

Comment: The comment section didn’t prove the forward direction either. It proved $\frac{x^2}{\left(d/2\right)^2} - \frac{y^2}{c^2-\left(d/2\right)^2}$so far.

Comment: It didn’t explain why the denominator under $y^2$ can be written as $b^2$. From the definition of a hyperbola, we only know $d>0$. Can you also please prove this step for the forward direction?

Comment: If the triangle is degenerate, then $c=d/2$ and the denominator under $y^2$ is $0$.

Comment: I think one should redefine the hyperbola to be such that $d \neq 2c$, or say that the formula is only for a non-degenerate hyperbola such that $d \neq 2c$.

Comment: A much simpler way (about half the steps) is to first prove the definition is equivalent to the formula AND the expression (the one with issues during squaring both sides) being greater or equal to zero. And then prove the formula implies that expression being greater or equal to $0$ in a few steps.

Comment: It may be that with a little more effort one of the sequences of implications can be made bidirectional. Also, good point about the degenerate triangle case. It's a limiting case of the hyperbola but generally not considered a hyperbola, so I've excluded it.